# How do I properly pass headers to each HTTP call in my Angular service?

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient, angular14

I'm using Angular 14. I have created the below service:

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HolidayCalendarService {
    ...
  private readonly headers: HttpHeaders;

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient,
    private configService: ConfigService,
    ...
  ) {    
    this.headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'appId': this.configService.config.appId});
  }

  add(obj: MyObject){
    return this.httpClient.post<MyResponse>(this.httpService.add(),myObj, {
        this.headers }).pipe(map((res: any) => res.data));
  }
```

I have a number of HTTP calls in the service, and for this reason I made `headers` a private property of the service. However, every time I reference `this.headers` in a method, I get this compilation error:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 15, '(url: string, body: any, options: { headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; } | undefined; observe: "events"; context?: HttpContext | undefined; params?: HttpParams | ... 1 more ... | undefined; reportProgress?: boolean | undefined; responseType?: "json" | undefined; withCredentials?: boolean | undefined; }): Observable<...>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '{ this: any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; } | undefined; observe: "events"; context?: HttpContext | undefined; params?: HttpParams | { ...; } | undefined; reportProgress?: boolean | undefined; responseType?: "json" | undefined; withCredentials?: boolean | undefined; }'.
```

I'm not quite sure what this means, especially because when I rewrite the method like this:

```
  add(obj: MyObject){
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'appId': this.configService.config.appId});
    return this.httpClient.post<MyResponse>(this.httpService.add(),myObj, {
        headers }).pipe(map((res: any) => res.data));
  }
```

everyting compiles.

Comment: The additional object wrapper for this.headers is probably incorrect here.

Comment: Nothing to do with TS or Angular, just basic JS syntax: `{ headers: this.headers }`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What ended up working was

```
  add(obj: MyObject){
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'appId': this.configService.config.appId});
    return this.httpClient.post<MyResponse>(this.httpService.add(),myObj, {
        headers: this.headers }).pipe(map((res: any) => res.data));
  }
```

Not sure why the route of defining a const worked but here we are.

Comment: You're not actually _using_ the `const` here...

Answer (score -1):

From what I can see I could say that it is a problem with obj: MyObject that receives the add() function, I think you should check the structure that has that object.

Comment: But that object is the same when I use "const headers = ..." instead of a member field and it works in the former case.  So it's probably nothing to do with the object, right?